Prime Factorization of a number implemented as a ternary search tree datastructure
Best to start with an example:
$$
826686=2 * 3^{10} * 7
$$
So by writing the nth prime as $p_n$ where n is called the index of the prime. (e.g. $23=p_9$ because it is the 9th prime occuring) we have the symbolic form:
$$
826686=p_1*p_2^{10}*p_4
$$
Now we can iterate this process by repeatedly replacing all numbers that we see with their prime factorization in symbolic form (replace $10$ by $p_1*p_3$, replace $4$ by $p_1^2$ and so on...)
$$
826686=p_1*p_{p_1}^{p_1*p_{p_{p_1}}}*p_{p_1^{p_1}}
$$
This iterative process always terminates and we can write every number in terms of "p's and 1's".
Few more examples:
$$
728 = p_1^{p_{p_1}}*p_{p_1^{p_1}}*p_{p_1*p_{p_1}}
$$$$
297 = p_{p_1}^{p_{p_1}}*p_{p_{p_{p_1}}}
$$$$
42 = p_1*p_{p_1}*p_{p_1^{p_1}}
$$$$
3141592653 = p_{p_1}*p_{p_1^{p_1}*p_{p_1^{p_1}}}*p_{p_1^{p_1}*p_{p_{p_{p_1}}*p_{p_1^{p_1}}}*p_{p_{p_1}*p_{p_1*p_{p_1}^{p_1}}}}
$$
Prime Factorizations displayed as a ternary tree (blue:exponentiation, green:multiplication, red:prime-"indexation" Pi(x)

So how could one go about implementing this as a datastructure? What programming languages are suitable for displaying this ternary tree in the way that I drew above (Inkscape)?
Thx

Your idea is cute, but I don't fully understand what you're asking.

Yeah you're right it is kindof open. For now I would just like to know how to generate this tree algorithmically so I can then display it for large numbers and marvel at its beauty and uniqueness...

Your trees are the same for all primes, semiprimes, products of three, or of four, or of five distinct primes etc. There are not that many different trees.

I don't understand what the question is.  When you talk about "implementing this as a datastructure", I don't understand what "this" refers to, and I don't understand what the issue is.  Why doesn't this just come down to factoring and then building a tree?  What is the challenge or difficulty?

$26=p_9$ numbering $2$ the 1st prime , the 9th is $23$?!

oops embarassing

@D.W yes how would you then build the tree from a factorization?

Here's what I came up with (in Haskell):
import Data.List (find, group)

primes = sieve [2..]
  where sieve (p : xs) = p : sieve (filter (\x -> x `mod` p /= 0) xs)

indexedPrimes = zip [1..] primes

factorize 1 = []
factorize n = i : factorize (n `div` p)
  where Just (i, p) = find (\(i, p) -> n `mod` p == 0) indexedPrimes

factorizeWithPowers = map (\l -> (head l, length l)) . group . factorize

So far, this factorizes a number using indices for the prime numbers, e.g.
ghci> factorizeWithPowers 826686
[(1,1),(2,10),(4,1)]
ghci> factorizeWithPowers 728
[(1,3),(4,1),(6,1)]

or $826686 = p_1^1 \cdot p_2^{10} \cdot p_4^1$
and $728 = p_1^3 \cdot p_4^1 \cdot p_6^1$.
Notice that factorization should be implemented much better, if this is to be applied to examples such as 3141592653 above. This is just for illustration purposes...
Then, the data structure for the ternary tree is:
data Tree = N | P Tree Tree Tree
  deriving (Eq, Show)

where N denotes the empty tree (or number 1), and P denotes a tree's node (your black dot). The order of the three operands are: exponentiation (blue), multiplication (green), prime-index (red).
The function that translates numbers to trees is:
tree = walk . factorizeWithPowers
  where walk [] = N
        walk ((i, e) : rest) = P (tree e) (walk rest) (tree i)

It gives, e.g.
ghci> tree 826686
P N (P (P N (P N N (P N N (P N N N))) N) (P N N (P (P N N N) N N)) (P N N N)) N
ghci> tree 728
P (P N N (P N N N)) (P N (P N N (P N (P N N (P N N N)) N)) (P (P N N N) N N)) N

Drawn as trees, these produce respectively:



The code that was used for drawing the trees using Tikz is the following:
tikz :: Integer -> IO ()
tikz = putStr . pp 2 prelude epilogue "" . tree
  where pp s prefix suffix chr N = ""
        pp s prefix suffix chr (P e m i) =
          prefix ++
          ind s ("node {}" ++ chr) ++
          pp (s + 1) (ind s "child {") (ind s "}") (par "exp") e ++
          pp (s + 1) (ind s "child {") (ind s "}") (par "mul") m ++
          pp (s + 1) (ind s "child {") (ind s "}") (par "ind") i ++
          suffix
        ind s str = replicate (2*s) ' ' ++ str ++ "\n"
        par str = " edge from parent[draw=" ++ str ++ "]"
        prelude = unlines [
            "\\documentclass[convert={density=150,outext=.png}]{standalone}",
            "\\usepackage{tikz}",
            "\\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}",
            "\\usegdlibrary{trees}",
            "\\begin{document}",
            "\\definecolor{exp}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,1.0}",
            "\\definecolor{mul}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,0.1}",
            "\\definecolor{ind}{rgb}{0.7,0.1,0.1}",
            "\\begin{tikzpicture}[",
            "  tree layout, very thick, grow=right,",
            "  nodes={draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt}",
            "  ]",
            "  \\draw"
          ]
        epilogue = unlines [
            "  ;",
            "\\end{tikzpicture}",
            "\\end{document}"
          ]


Thank you so much! Will take a while for me to understand this but I'm determined :)
